# Backpropagation issue with custom loss function

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, backpropagation, fast-ai

**Context**

I am building a super-resolution imaging model (a U-Net). My data consists of microscopic blood smears. I am using fast ai.
I want to try a new loss function that would "focus" on the cells' components.

**What I have done**

I have created a ***pseudo_mask*** function that takes two arguments, an image and an integer β ranging from 0 to 255. This function first computes a cell segmenting mask, converts the 0 values of the mask to β and applies the result to the original image.

[Pseudo_mask output of the same image, with β values of respectively 0, 122 and 255 (e.g. the original image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU2ff.png)

I want to create a custom loss function that would compute the MSE on the output of the pseudo_mask function and backpropagate it to the original image.

My code is fairly trivial as I simply "completed" the Pytorch MSE loss function.

```
class MSE_Mask_Loss(_Loss):

   def __init__(self, size_average=None, reduce=None, reduction: str = 'mean') -> None:
       super(MSE_Mask_Loss, self).__init__(size_average, reduce, reduction)

   def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:

        input = tensor_pseudo_mask(input,255)
        target = tensor_pseudo_mask(target,255)
             
       return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
```

The code runs fine but I assume there are some issues with the backpropagation since results obtained with this loss and β=255 are terrible, while they should be equivalent to the (good) ones obtained with original images.

What I am doing wrong?

---

**Edit**

The tensor_pseudo_mask is defined as follows:

```
def tensor_pseudo_mask(tns,val):

  for i in range(len(tns)):

    tns[i,:,:,:] = pseudo_mask(tns[i,:,:,:],val).data

  return tns.cuda()
```

where

```
def convert(x, val):

  if x == 0:
    return val
  else:
    return x

vecfunc = np.vectorize(convert)

def apply_mask(img, mask):

  tensor_mask = torch.unsqueeze(torch.Tensor(mask) / 255, 2) #For broadcasting
  img_masked = tensor_mask * torch.Tensor(convert_Image_RGB(img))

  return Image(convert_RGB_Image(img_masked)) 

def pseudo_mask(img, val):

  mask_value = torch.Tensor(np.array(mask(img)))
  pseudo_mask = vecfunc(mask_value, val)
  applied_pseudo_mask = apply_mask(img,pseudo_mask)

  return applied_pseudo_mask
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your code for `tensor_pseudo_mask`. Also `input` is your variable which is backpropagated, hence your choice of what can be done with this `tensor` is a little bit limited to differentiable operations (you can do whatever you want with `target` though).

Comment: Thanks for the wishes and the explanation. 
It makes sense, I guess I tried the brute force without given it enough thoughts.

In case anyone is interested, I somehow bypassed the issue by applying the mask to the "loss tensor" itself, rather than the input/output.

Comment: Yes, you could that as in this case values won't be backpropagated if you zero out the loss.